# Unable get desired output as per the code in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[I have tried in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g7nwvwat/#&togetherjs=gCa0lP3tmP) an html code which displays seatlayout on a webpage.

We will add seats in `#place` element using JavaScript.
To make it generalize, `settings` object is used:

`rows`: total number of rows of seats.

`cols`: total number of seats in each row.

`rowCssPrefix`: will be used to customize row layout using (`rowCssPrefix` + `row number`) css class.

`colCssPrefix`: will be used to customize column using (`colCssPrefix` + column number) css class.

`seatWidth`: width of seat.

`seatHeight`: height of seat.

`seatCss`: css class of seat.

`selectedSeatCss`: css class of already booked seats.

`selectingSeatCss`: css class of selected seats.

`init` method is used to draw seats layout. Already booked seats array will be passed as argument of this method.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<link rel="javascript" type="text/javascript">


<script>
   
     var   settings = {
           rows: 5,
           cols: 15,
           rowCssPrefix: 'row-',
           colCssPrefix: 'col-',
           seatWidth: 35,
           seatHeight: 35,
           seatCss: 'seat',
           selectedSeatCss: 'selectedSeat',
           selectingSeatCss: 'selectingSeat'
       };
<!--rows: total number of rows of seats.
    cols: total number of seats in each row.
    rowCssPrefix: will be used to customize row layout using(rowCssPrefix + row number) css class.
 colCssPrefix: will be used to customize column using (colCssPrefix + column number) css class.
    seatWidth: width of seat.
    seatHeight: height of seat.
    seatCss: css class of seat.
    selectedSeatCss: css class of already booked seats.
    selectingSeatCss: css class of selected seats.->
  <!-- init method is used to draw seats layout. Already booked seats array will be passed as argument of this method.->
    var init=function(reservedSeat) {
                 
            var str = [], seatNo, className;
              for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                
                 for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                         
                    seatNo = (i + j * settings.rows + 1);                                              
                    className = settings.seatCss + ' ' +    settings.rowCssPrefix + i.toString()    + ' ' + settings.colCssPrefix +   j.toString();                             if ($.isArray(reservedSeat) &&  $.inArray(seatNo, reservedSeat) != -1) {
              className += ' ' + settings.selectedSeatCss;
                    }
                    str.push('<li id="' + className + '"' +
                              'style="top:' + (i *   settings.seatHeight).toString() + 'px;left:' + (j *   settings.seatWidth).toString() + 'px">' +
                              '<a title="' + seatNo + '">' + seatNo +   '</a>' +
                              '</li>');
                }
              }
            $('#place').html(str.join(''));
        }; 
        //case I: Show from starting
        //init();

        //Case II: If already booked
       
        var bookedSeats = [5, 10, 25];

        init(bookedSeats);
    
</script>
<!--  we need to add style -->
<style>
#holder{    
height:200px;    
width:550px;
background-color:#F5F5F5;
border:1px solid #A4A4A4;
margin-left:10px;   
}
#place {
position:relative;
margin:7px;
}
#place a{
font-size:0.6em;
}
#place li
{
list-style: none outside none;
position: absolute;   
}    
#place li:hover
{
background-color:yellow;      
} 
#place seat{
background-color: blue;
background:url("seat.gif") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;*/
height:33px;
width:33px;
display:block;   
}
#place.selectedSeat
{ 

background-image:url("seat.gif");          
}
#place.selectingSeat
{ 
background-image:url("seat.gif");        
}
#place .row-3, #place .row-4{
margin-top:10px;
}
#seatDescription li{
verticle-align:middle;    
list -style: none outside none;
padding-left:35px;
height:35px;
float:left;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<h2> Choose seats by clicking the corresponding seat in the layout        below:</h2>
<div id="holder"> 
    <ul  id="place">
    </ul>    
 <!-- We will add seats in “#place” element using javascript.-->
 </div>
 <div style="float:left;"> 
 <ul id="seatDescription">
    <li style="background:url('seat.gif') no-repeat scroll 0 0  transparent;">Available Seat</li>
    <li style="background:url('seat.gif') no-repeat scroll 0 0  transparent;">Booked Seat</li>
     <li style="background:url('seat.gif') no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;">Selected Seat</li>
   </ul>
   </div>
     <div style="clear:both;width:100%">
     <input type="button" id="btnShowNew" value="Show Selected Seats" />       <input type="button" id="btnShow" value="Show All" />  
     <input type="button" id="b1" value="Seatlayout"/>         
    </div>
   </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: whats wrong with this code ? why i am not getting desired output

Comment: Its difficult to guess from this code, could you post the errors which your getting and it would be great if you could dump your code in jsfiddle and  let us know what your expecting. **Its always  good to show a live example of the issue**, http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: i was expecting the output could be something like getting seats in the empty box

Comment: hmm, like i said its difficult to visualise the output by analysing your code which is more than 20 lines. so if you can create a jsfiddle, it will be easy to understand the issue.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/g7nwvwat/#&togetherjs=gCa0lP3tmP

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/g7nwvwat/#&togetherjs=gCa0lP3tmP

Comment: you have not included jquery library in your script, try adding that and it should work as expected. place this script reference inside your head tag `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" />`. for more understanding you can check this jsfiddle,https://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/g7nwvwat/1/

Comment: In addition to @dreamweiver's comment, add the jQuery library _before_ your own script.